# javascript adding multiple variables to mailto body with a for loop

Tags: javascript

This function below is supposed to add some of the variables "mess" into the body of an email message. The "who" and "what" gets read in the email address and subject ok, and the first line of the mess variables "ISBN" gets read into the body as it should...but the rest of the mess variables that should be read into the body does not get entered. Wondering if the for loop is not looping correctly. Just trying to narrow the problem down. Any help would very nice.

```
function mailOrder()
{
   who=document.order.Email.value;
   what="order";
   var mess = "";
   for (var n = 0; n < bookDB.length; n++) 
   {
    bookNum = bookDB[n].quantity;
    if (bookNum > 0) 
       {       
       mess += "ISBN: " + bookDB[n].number + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
       mess += "Book Name: " + bookDB[n].title + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
       mess += "Quantity Ordered: " + bookDB[n].quantity + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
       mess += "Book Price: " + bookDB[n].price + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
       mess += " ***************************************************** ";
       }        
   }
   mess +="Customer Name: " + document.order.Name.value + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
   mess +="Email Address: " + document.order.Email.value + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
   mess +="Address: " + document.order.Address.value + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
   mess +="City: " + document.order.City.value + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
   mess +="Country: " + document.order.Country.value + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"; 
   parent.location.href='mailto:'+who+'?subject='+what+'&body='+mess;
}
```

Comment: I think you want `length` instead of `quantity` in `bookDB[n].quantity;`

Comment: Unless that is some kind of nonstandard object.

Comment: thanks for your reply...The bookDB[n].quantity and the if statement is to ensure only items selected from the database is added to the email.

Comment: You can throw some `console.log("some thing to tell you where this is")` in there to see what is getting executed. Why are you relaying on this values already being set, rather than passing them into the function like `function mailOrder(bookDB, who, what)` or something like that? I am assuming you have a reason, since this could open you up to scope issues and values changing unexpectedly.

Comment: Thanks for your help...The problem was with the concatenating of the string...deleting the "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" in each line corrected the problem. So now all values associated to the variable "mess" are displayed in the users email body. Though a users email program may not always be available to the code so not as efficient to maybe a cgi script... something else to work on.

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at mailgun.com they have a nice system.